# What does the `*` mean in a generic type?

Tags: scala, generics, scala-cats

I was learning Cats library and found `*` as a generic type, like that:

```scala
implicit def catsDataSemigroupKForValidated[A](implicit A: Semigroup[A]): SemigroupK[Validated[A, *]] =
  new SemigroupK[Validated[A, *]] {
    def combineK[B](x: Validated[A, B], y: Validated[A, B]): Validated[A, B] = x match {
      case v @ Valid(_) => v
      case Invalid(ix) =>
        y match {
          case Invalid(iy)  => Invalid(A.combine(ix, iy))
          case v @ Valid(_) => v
        }
    }
  }
```

My guess is that the `*` is used, because the `combineK` method return `Validated[A, B]` so there is no need to specify generic type. Or it could be `Any` type (like Inteliij is suggested). I would be very glad for your explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cats code you are looking at is master branch, which is for Dotty (Scala 3). `*` is a type parameter placeholder in 3.0:

https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/wildcards.html

Note that it is already deprecated in 3.2 and removed in 3.3 in favor for `_`.

---

EDIT

It's also used in kind projector plugin

Comment: Note "a wildcard" and "a type parameter placeholder" are entirely different; `*` in 3.0 with `-Ykind-projector` is a placeholder, _not_ a wildcard.

Comment: This answer still isn't really correct at all. Currently Cats doesn't even cross-build on Dotty on master. The `*` is syntax provided by [kind-projector](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector), a widely used Scala 2 compiler plugin. Dotty temporarily supports `*` for compatibility with Scala 2 code that uses kind-projector (like Cats).