# Difference between * (star) and _ (underscore) in type parameter

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, kind-projector

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565393/what-does-the-mean-in-a-generic-type) someone says that star is underscore from scala 3, but I've seen some code like this in scala 2.13:

```
def make[F[_]: ContextShift: MonadError[*[_], Throwable]: Effect: Logging](): ...
```

Does it have a same meaning and just specify that type in * is not the same as in _?

Comment: *[_] comes from kind-projector plugin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`_` denotes (depending on context)

- type constructor - if used as in a type parameter definition/constraint

  ```
  def foo[F[_]]: Unit
  ```
- existential type - if applied to something that should be used as a proper type

  ```
  def bar(f: F[_]): F[_]
  ```

Here we want to understand the type constructor.

Type constructor would be (simplifying) that `F` of something, that doesn't yet have that something defined, but we can apply `A` to it and make it a `F[A]`. E.g.

- `List` could be passed as `F[_]` because it has a gap, if we fill it with e.g. `String` it could become `List[String]`
- `Option` could be passed as `F[_]` as well, it has a gap, if we filled it with e.g. `Int` it would become `Option[Int]`
- `Double` cannot be used as `F[_]`, because it doesn't have a gap

Types with a "gap" are often denoted as `* -> *`, while types without them as `*`. We could read `*` simply as a type, while `* -> *` as "type that takes another type to form a type" - or a type constructor.

(Higher-kinded types like one just mentioned are complex thing on its own, so it would be better for you to learn about them more outside of that question).

`*` (from [kind projector plugin](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector)) is used for kind projection - the syntax is inspired from the notation above to show where type would be passed if we wanted to create a new type:

```
Monad[F[List[*]]]
```

is really like:

```
type UsefulAlias[A] = F[List[A]]
Monad[UsefulAlias]
```

except that it works without a type alias.

If it was Dotty, it could be better expressed with a [type lambda](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/type-lambdas-spec.html):

```
// Monad[F[List[*]]] is equal to
[A] =>> Monad[List[A]]
```

In your example:

```
def make[F[_]: ContextShift: MonadError[*[_], Throwable]: Effect: Logging](): ...
```

- `F[_]` is defined as type constructor - so you cannot pass there `String`, `Int` or `Byte`, but you could pass there `List`, `Future` or `Option` (because they take one type parameter)
- `F[_]: ContextShift` is a shortcut for `[F[_]](implicit sth: ContextShift[F])` - we can see that `ContextShift` takes as a parameter something that takes a type parameter on its own (like `F[_]`)
- `[F[_]: MonadError[*[_], Throwable]` could be expanded to:

  ```
  type Helper[G[_]] = MonadError[G, Throwable]
  [F[_]: Helper]
  ```

  which in turn could be rewritten as

  ```
  type Helper[G[_]] = MonadError[G, Throwable]
  [F[_]](implicit me: Helper[F])
  ```

  or using a type lambda

  ```
  [F[_]] =>> MonadError[F, Throwable]
  ```

It would probably be easier to read if it was written as:

```
def make[F[_]: ContextShift: MonadError[*, Throwable]: Effect: Logging]():
```

Thing is, that `*` would suggest that expected type is

```
[A] =>> MonadError[A, Throwable]
```

meanwhile kindness of `*` should be `* -> *` instead of `*`. So this `*[_]` means "we want to create a new type constructor here by making this thing in place of `*` a parameter, but we want to denote that this parameter is of kind `* -> *` instead of `*`

```
[F[_]] =>> MonadError[F, Throwable]
```

so we'll add `[_]` to show the compiler that it is a type constructor.

It is quite a lot to absorb, and it should be easier, I can only feel sorry and say that in Dotty it will be clearer.